# How do i delete a file in remote location

Tags: rsync

I have delete 1 file locally and added new files locally, i dont want to sync those new files to the remote system but rather delete only the one that has been removed from src.I tried the command below but it deletes file from remote also.

```
rsync -avh --delete /home/ssastry/ ssastry@10.196.105.121:/tmp
```

I want the only file deleted from local to get deleted from remote . i dont want new additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command.

```
rsync -r --delete --existing --ignore-existing /home/ssastry/ ssastry@10.196.105.121:/tmp
```

From man page:

> --existing :skip creating new files on receiver
>
> --ignore-existing    :   skip updating files that exist on receiver